# C# automatic update data from db

Tags: c#, sql

I am building two applications that work on the same database. My problem is that i want to create an automatic update.

Details :

I have a farmacy and on the main form i am displaying some data (list of medicines  for example).
   I have another application that allows me to add/edit/delete drugs.

I want the first application to update from time to time (1-2 seconds).

I tried creating another thread in the main application and call it with a 2 seconds sleep, but it frezees the application and i don't want that. I want the applications (both of them) to be functional and do a background update somehow.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) would allow you to do this.

Comment: i will try this in the week-end.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an instance of `System.Threading.Timer` to update the display every X seconds, you can rely on the tick callback to be on a background thread. This will keep the display from freezing.

Remember, you can only access controls on the thread they were updated on. If you need to access a control on a worker thread, you can use the InvokeRequired/Invoke pattern (in WinForms).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360). It will help you do stuffs in background and update your views (Forms) later.